# my code always give convergencewarning for every iteration(even 1) please give a solution to that

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1wr6.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t0mG.png)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY8KD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwKBA.png)

i want to examine the impact and stability of four kernel functions with feature
selection on the performance of SVM for software defect prediction. Strictly speaking,
i want to examine the performance of nonlinear kernel functions against linear kernel function. I try solve this using pipeline but while solving it gives convergence warning for every time even max_iter=1 also. Please give a solution to run the code without any convergence warning